# What does Paul mean about "terrible purpose"?

Tags: dune

In *Dune* book 1, there are various mention of "terrible purpose" in the thinking of Paul and he also mention quite a few times that he didn't want the "jihad" to happen. What is this whole thing about?

> The thought was both reassuring and frustrating. Somewhere ahead of him on this path, the fanatic hordes cut their gory path across the universe in his name. The green and black Atreides banner would become a symbol of terror. Wild legions would charge into battle screaming their war cry: "Muad'Dib!" It must not be, he thought. I cannot let it happen. But he could feel the demanding race consciousness within him, his own terrible purpose, and he knew that no small thing could deflect the juggernaut.

Comment: why don't you just finish reading the books?  any answer will inevitably contain spoilers.

Comment: I need to be sured of I am not missing something because English is not my mother language. The text is confusing and the author tried to mystify the thing by not telling something clearly.

Comment: Any answer for this would be a spoiler; keep on reading.

Comment: You can't claim you're concerned that your lack of mastery of the language is causing problems, and then turn around and accuse the author of attempting to "mystify the thing by not telling it clearly". The answer is very clear, even I the passage you quoted.

Comment: You didn't miss anything so far, this *terrible purpose* will be revealed later on.

Comment: I agree, that's a major plot point that is revealed in the book quite deftly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the quotation you included states, Paul foresees that hordes of fanatical followers will rampage across the galaxy, wreaking terrible destruction in his name under the guise of religious beliefs centered around him.  His "terrible purpose" is to be the focus that creates this religious "holy war" (i.e. jihad).

The reasons why this jihad is inevitable are clarified later in the book, and explained in more detail in later books.

> Essentially, as the Kwisatz Haderach, Paul's mastery of prescience and the inner voices of his genetic memory guide him on to establish the beginnings of *the Golden Path*, which dictates events that shape the role and destiny of humanity for thousands of years, with the ultimate goal of saving them from an unnamed deadly menace that would otherwise destroy all of human kind.  Paul understands to an undisclosed extent that this sole path to survival for the species will entail horrible deeds, terrible suffering, and general oppression and misery of the vast majority of humans.

Comment: Okay. Could you tell me when will he reveal this? In book 1?

Comment: Which part? The non-spoiler, or the spoiler?

Comment: I want to know where is the spoiler part in the book, is it in book 2 or book 1?

Comment: Iirc, the jihad is explained in book 1, with more detail in book 2. The *Golden Path* idea is explained in books 3 and 4.